# UITextField Delegate method doesn't get triggered

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to limit the number of characters that the user can enter to 1.

```
 class ActivationViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var activationCodeTextField1: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          self.activationCodeTextField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textField1DidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
            self.activationCodeTextField1.delegate = self
     }

     @IBAction func textField1DidChange(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         print("TextField1DidChange")
         
         }

    
    func activationCodeTextField1(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // You can check for other things besides length here as well.
        print("isValidLength: ", isValidLength(textField: activationCodeTextField1, range: range, string: string))
        return isValidLength(textField: activationCodeTextField1, range: range, string: string)
    }

    private func isValidLength(textField: UITextField, range: NSRange, string: String) -> Bool {
        let length = ((textField.text ?? "").utf16).count + (string.utf16).count - range.length
        return length <= 1
    }
    
}
```

However, the function `activationCodeTextField1` doesn't get triggered and this line inside of it doesn't print anything:

```
print("isValidLength: ", isValidLength(textField: activationCodeTextField1, range: range, string: string))
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the name of delegate methods. The correct function is

```
optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield)

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple textFields.

Comment: Then check which textField called the delege. `if textField == activationCodeTextField1`

Comment: Though you have multiple text field, this method will only call if you assign a delegate to self. And you can also compare textfields.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called any of the method from UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Please checkout link to find methods in UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate